# Chinese character "denoting" or "used to denote" black color?

Tags: writing, gerunds

How to say the following phrase correctly:
a Chinese character **denoting** OR **used to denote** black colour?

Context

> Furthermore, due to the etymological analysis of **a Chinese character denoting black color**, peculiarities of cultural information that concerns appropriate lexical unit of Chinese language are determined.

Comment: I think that both are fine and there's no difference in terms of meaning.

Comment: If the usage of that Chinese character is current, "used to denote" could be interpreted as meaning that it no longer represents the colour *black*, or it has been replaced by a different character.

Comment: Could you please say whether the Chinese character is still currently in use  or if it has become obsolete/archaic?

Comment: @Mari-LouA This charater is still in use -  黑.

Comment: If it is clear from the context that the character has not fallen in disuse, then both forms I'd say are fine. Otherwise, to avoid any possible ambiguity, chose the version "denoting black color".

Comment: Both ***denoting*** and ***used to denote*** are perfectly natural in the cited context. The big giveaway that it didn't come from a native speaker is because we'd say ***...the colour black***, not ***black colour***.

Comment: Yeah... well...it's not wrong though. I would have said: ... a Chinese character which means/signifies *black*...